# Are there destroy_all!/delete_all! in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

We are looking for a command to delete multiple records within Rails `transaction`. To make it trigger within `transaction`, we used `destroy_all!` and `delete_all!` and received `method not defined` error. What's the right delete command (or right way) for multiple records which triggers in Rails transaction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there are no methods called `delete_all!` or `destroy_all!`. See [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html).

Use `delete_all` or `destroy_all` instead. These methods will raise ActiveRecord errors if deletion fails. It means your transaction will be rolled back in case of errors as you expected.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it doesn't look like this is correct. A `destroy_all` calls `destroy` not `destroy!`, so it will not raise

Comment: `destroy_all` raises error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed`. Checked on Rails 7

Answer (score 1):

No `delete_all!` or `destroy_all!` in Rails, but Rails has [delete_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class) and [destroy_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/destroy_all/class) methods. Diference between these two methods are: `delete_all` only deletes the matching records with the given condition but doesn't delete the dependant/associated records where `destroy_all` deletes all the matching records along with their dependant/associated records. So, choose wisely between `delete_all` and `destroy_all` according to your need.

Answer (score 1):

There are no methods called `delete_all!` or `destroy_all!` but look at the `destroy_all`source code:

```
def destroy_all(conditions = nil)
    find(:all, :conditions => conditions).each { |object| object.destroy }
end
```

It calls method destroy and so I do not see any exceptions raise here. You can use this.

```
records.each &:destroy!
```

Comment: this might be a bit dangerous since it's not an atomic transaction. ie. if you encounter a validation error in one of the records the previous ones have all been already deleted and you might encounter data integrity issues.

Answer (score 1):

The source code of destroy_all is:

```
def destroy_all(conditions = nil)
 find(:all, :conditions => conditions).each { |object| object.destroy }
end
```

and `object.destroy` will only return false not raise errors to trigger transaction when deletion fails.

So, May be we need use it like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
  records.each(&:destroy!) 
end
```

Right?